# how can I create css news ticker for AMP-HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, amp-html

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/markgonz007/jC8uq/) is a good example with jquery but it is not valid jQuery for AMP

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        var ticker_holder = $('.ticker-holder').get(0);
        var ticker_text = $('.ticker').get(0);
        var ticker_pos = ticker_text.parentNode.offsetWidth;

        var ticker_data = $(ticker_holder).html();
        $(ticker_text).parent().html('<marquee scrollamount="10" scrolldelay="">' + ticker_data + '</marquee>');

        $('.emergencyalert').hover(

        function() {
            $('marquee', this).get(0).stop();
        }, function() {
            $('marquee', this).get(0).start();
        });


    }
    catch (o) {}
});
```

Is there any component in AMP to do something like that?

Comment: You should read https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/. You will not be able to load jQuery; you'll need vanilla JS. Also, you may have to bind your new function to a user action; not sure if you can bind it to a container.

Answer (score 0):

`<marquee>` element was removed from HTML5. I suggest you can achieve marquee effect from css animations. AMP doesn't have any such component which has functionality like marquee. Here is code i tested in AMP playground and adds marquee like effect. You can modify it further to achieve exact same effect you looking for.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-autocomplete/index.html">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>

  <title>amp-autocomplete</title>

  <style amp-custom>
    .wrap{
      position: relative;
    }
    .ul-list{
      list-style: none;
      
    }
    .li-list{
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 1em 2em;
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    .spot-anim {
      position: absolute;
      right: -1em;
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      will-change: transform;
      animation-duration: 30s;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-name: marquee;
      -moz-animation: marquee;
      -o-animation-name: marquee;
      animation-name: marquee;
    }
  </style>

  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    
    <ul class="ul-list spot-anim">
      <li class="li-list"> News number 1</li>
      <li class="li-list"> News number 2</li>
      <li class="li-list"> News number 3</li>
      <li class="li-list"> News number 4</li>
  </ul>
  
  </div>
  <style amp-keyframes>

        @keyframes marquee {
          0% {
          transform: translateX(100%);
          }
          100% {
          transform: translateX(-150%);
          }
        }

  </style>
</body></html>
```

You may also use amp-script with layout="fixed-height" here to achieve same animations with stop functionality on mouse over event with javascript.